# Setting checkboxes and radiobuttons with FPDM in PDF form

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox

I'm trying to fill out a PDF form through FPDM, like in this example: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php

Filling out text, date, decimal, ... inputs works correctly, but I can't find out how to check checkboxes and grouped checkboxes (radio buttons). This are two problems:

1. Checkboxes have a regular name, like "mycheck1". Setting the value in the PHP array to `true` or or `"true"` or `"1"` or `1` or `"checked"` or `"on"` or `"yes"` doesn't activate the checkboxes (case-sensitively tested too). Which value do I have to set to activate checkboxes?
2. Grouped checkboxes (radio buttons) cannot even be found - the script throws the error `"FPDF-Merge Error: field yourtype not found"`. What is the correct name? Adobe Acrobat Pro DC shows the name "yourtype" as the name for all checkboxes in the group. In the field-list it shows the grouped checkboxes as "yourtype#0", "yourtype#1", "yourtype#2", etc. But the script doesn't seem to be able to find any of this names. I also tried something like "yourtype[1]" without luck. And as soon as I can access them, do I have to set the value for one of them, or do I assign the (integer?) value just directly?

My example:

```
<?php
    require('fpdm.php');

    $fields = array(
    'forname' => 'Jon Dow',  // text input: works
    'mycheck1' => true,  // checkbox: doesn't work! Also tried "true", 1, "1", "yes", "on", ... (with case-sensitive)
    'yourtype' => true,  // grouped checkbox (radio button): doesn't even find input with that name.
    );

    $pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
    $pdf->Load($fields, true);
    $pdf->Merge();
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

**Edit: The FPDM class does not seem to support setting some types like checkboxes and dropdowns. In the file `fpdm.php` says the following in the header unter the ToDo section: `extends filling to another form fields types (checkboxes,combos..)`**

Comment: I wrote my own PDF parser now, which can fill forms, so I'm not in hurry anymore. But it would still be interesting if and how I could do it with the FPDM class.

Comment: your own PDF parser supports text and checkboxes? If yes, could you please share your own parser?

Comment: @cooler Yes, it can read / write text inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons, ... The parsed values are stored in an abstract structure (array based), so it is possible to modify any values in a low-level like way. I also implemented some high level functions (e. g. to fill out multiple inputs at once). However, it does not support "linearized" PDF docs or docs which have "incremental updates". The PDF docs must be saved as new docs previously ("Save as...") or made compatible with a tool like "pdftk" (freeware). It was part of our project, so I have to ask first if I'm allowed to publish it.

Comment: @wizard That's seems awesome! Do you know if you could share it? In any case, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned it's not supported in fpdm. I was looking for another library that allow doing this and I found this : [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk)

Code sample :

```
// Fill form with data array
$pdf = new Pdf('doc.pdf');
$pdf->fillForm([
        'CheckBox1' =>'Yes',
        'RadioButton'=>'Choice1',
        'name'=>'Wizard'
    ])
    ->needAppearances()
    ->saveAs('doc_filled.pdf');
```

Comment: https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk this library works fine with checkbox and radio button. I have to use this too instead of FPDM library.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I had this problem and have been trying to figure it out using FPDM. Checkbox fields have an Export value on Adobe Acrobat, this value is by default 'Yes' but it can be another value depending on language or if changed manually by the user.
If the value is then assigned on FPDM it will mark the checkbox correctly when downloading it and viewing it in Adobe's pdf reader. However there seems to be problems with web viewers. 
Firefox will display the text overlayed as a string inside the checkbox, while chrome did not manage to display any check at all. It might be a problem on my side but since I only need the pdf reader support I did not do further research.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention, that I did found out why it didn't worked: Because FPDM does not support it at all. In the fpdm.php in the top header it says under "todo": `extends filling to another form fields types (checkboxes,combos..)`.

Answer (score 1):

For prefill a pdf I have used https://www.sitepoint.com/filling-pdf-forms-pdftk-php/ this link.

We can follow the follwing steps:
1. Install pdftk toolkit and pdftk server.
2. Covert your pdf to pdftk pdf using following command in cmd:
pdftk your.pdf output coverted.pdf
(Use the converted pdf in the script)
3. Follow the steps mentioned in - https://www.sitepoint.com/filling-pdf-forms-pdftk-php/
4. Now use the following command:
pdftk sample.pdf dump_data_fields output fields.txt
(A text file generated with various options as below)

FieldType: Button
FieldName: topmostSubform[0].Page5[0].Gender[0]
FieldNameAlt: 8. Sex. Male
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Off

### FieldStateOption: male

FieldType: Button
FieldName: topmostSubform[0].Page5[0].Gender[1]
FieldNameAlt: Female
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Female

### FieldStateOption: Off

5.) In php we can work like:
require_once (dirname(**FILE**) . '/../../../vendor/fpdm/PdfForm.php');

```
    $male = $female = '';
    if ($customer_data['gender'] == 'male') {
        $male = 'male';
        $female = 'Off';
    } else {
        $male = 'Off';
        $female = 'Female';
    }

    $field_data = array(
        'topmostSubform[0].Page5[0].Gender[0]' => $male,
        'topmostSubform[0].Page5[0].Gender[1]' => $female,
    );
    $pdf = new \PdfForm(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../vendor/fpdm/ssn_form.pdf', $field_data);
    //  $pdf->save('outputs/form-filled.pdf');
    $pdf->save('outputs/form-filled.pdf');
    //$pdf->download();
    $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../outputs/form-filled.pdf';
    $filename = 'form-filled.pdf';
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    @readfile($file);
    exit;
```

6.) Checkboxes worked prefilled by using the value in FieldStateOption in txt file.

Thanks, I hope this will help.